# Can not Serializable member System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite error in Web Service Application

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, asmx

i have a web service applicatiin which is gets data from sql server database.I want to get product my database so i wrote a method like below : what should I do?

```
 public class ProductBusiness :System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProductImage { get; set; }


[WebMethod()]
    public List<ProductBusiness> getProduct()
    {
        using (HealthyFoodEntities db = new HealthyFoodEntities())
        {
            var query = from x in db.Products
                        select new ProductBusiness
                        {
                            ProductImage = x.Picture,
                            ProductName = x.ProductName
                        };
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you serializing a `WebService`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.I just have a web service class and i want to get product from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return the instance of `ProductBusiness` class, because that itself will be reference to instance of `Service`.

So Either change your Service class name, something like this:-

```
public class ProductBusinessService :System.Web.Services.WebService
```

Or else, separate your custom class from service class & rename it to something else, like this:-

```
public class ProductBusinessData
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProductImage { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use it in your Service:-

```
[WebMethod]
public List<ProductBusinessData> getProduct()
{
  //Your Code
}
```